# Can I remove the first "que" in "un juego que hay que jugar"?

Tags: gramática

I saw these sentences on a pamphlet recently:

> La vida no es un deporte para expectadores. Es un juego que hay que jugar.

This is how I'd translate the sentence into English:

> Life is not a sport for spectators. It is a game that you have to play.

However in English, you can (and, in speech, likely *would*) remove the word *that* in the second sentence (leaving it to read "It is a game you have to play.")

I'm wondering if this is permissible in the Spanish as well. Can I remove the first *que* in that sentence? Is this version acceptable, and if so, which is more likely to be said in casual conversation?

> La vida no es un deporte para expectadores. Es un juego hay que jugar.

Answer (score 8):

In short: you can not.

In long: in english, 'that' may be understood even when not present. In spanish, it must be present as the introducing particle.

Note that even changing it for a comma changes meaning:

"Es un juego que hay que jugar" -> "It is a game **that** one must play"

"Es un juego, hay que jugar" -> "It is a game **so** one must play"

Comment: Es uno de las cosas que siempre confundo en el ingles a todo le quiero poner el `that` delante. Como se usa en español

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it as:

> Life is not a sport for spectators. It is a game that has to be played.

In the first sentence, Life is not a sport; Then the second says that "it [life] has to be played". The overall meaning of the sentence is, "Do not watch life, live it".

> "Es un juego que hay que jugar" -> "It is a game that one must play"
>
> "Es un juego, hay que jugar" -> "It is a game so one must play"

These translations do not work exactly. The word "one" is a bit awkward. The sentences describe "the game", which is life, not that a person has to play the game, but there can be different interpretations of the entire meaning as a whole.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So you do think the first *que* is necessary, then? If you don't like the *one* translation, what do you think the version with the comma means?

Comment: I am certain that "que" is necessary. My translation of the sentence with commas is: "It is a game, so it (instead of "one") has to be played." The overall sentence describes the _game_ of life. Envite knows that life has to be played by someone, so he uses the word "one".

Comment: Ohh, I see! That's very insightful. Thank you very much for sharing! +1!